# Limit how much GPU an app gets to use

Tags: macos, performance, monterey, gpu

How can I set a hard cap on how much of the GPU an app is allowed to use?

Like AppPolice, but for GPU, and preferably not a third-party program but please recommend me those anyway (I couldn't find any while searching just now)

On a 2015 Intel MacBook Pro with Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB graphics

Comment: What’s the problem you’re trying to solve with this?

Comment: Agree with Allan - you're going to get a "no - can't be done" answer quickly which may or may not be correct. Also - we might need to know what hardware you care about specifically and which OS - Apple has dramatically changed things and you might get a good answer for old OS and old hardware that's not even possible with the new...

Comment: Many apps that are expected to run a GPU hard have internal controls - Photoshop, games etc.

Comment: @Allan stop Minecraft from making my fans whirr and draining the battery. Minecraft doesn't seem to have internal controls for this, even with mods. The best I can do is play in a tiny Window instead of fullscreen

Comment: @bmike has the answer.  See my follow on comment for details.

Comment: Reducing the GPU needs in the Minecraft configuration is the way to go: reduce rendering quality, reduce window size, reduce rendering/simulation distance etc. a direct restricting of GPU consumption would basically do the same (an app can‘t render 4K quality with limited GPU access).

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly sure GPU controls are not possible on Apple Silicon and recent macOS versions. The best you could do is choose App Tamer and control the CPU / process threads and indirectly throttle the GPU since nothing hits the GPU without passing the CPU first.

- https://www.defaultfolder.com/AppTamer/index.html

Comment: I don’t believe that GPU controls are available on Intel either.  From my limited  understanding of GPU programming, it’s different from programming a multi-threadded/multi-core (CPU) app.  The GPU manufacturer provides an SDK and libraries that you access; if there is any sort of “cap” it would be hard coded and not user adjustable.

Comment: Right on @Allan - the MacBook Pro that had two GPU discrete and integrated could do things and messing with kernel extensions (kext) in the past were ways to alter things so unless / until Apple decides to make an API/SDK for messing with the scheduling of the integrated GPU - we may be at the end of the list for macOS.